# Turn off ReSharper underline for ASP.NET Core MVC views and redirections

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, resharper, resharper-2022

Since I've installed ReSharper all ActionResults in my ASP.NET Core MVC controllers are underlined in red, that applies to both Views and e.g. redirect to actions.

[image: RedirectToAction]

or

[image: returnView]

AFAIR there is some feature behind it - R# indicates if view is present and allows to navigate to it. Cool. But currently every time I look in the code all I see are those red underlined expressions. They are more visible than any error, warnings or hints and therefore quite annoying, as they don't really need any attention.

I've checked R# settings, but couldn't find any feature responsible for it. I've checked `Fonts & Colors` section of VS config, but none of Resharper entries there has underline defined.

Any idea how can I turn this off, or make it appear only if there is an actual error? or make it somehow less visible?

**UPDATE**: to be clear, there is no action available for those items. The only suggestion of R# is to turn nameof expression to constant and typical string literals on the action name:

[image]

Comment: There should be an action list associated with the inspection ().

Comment: there isn't really, it suggests to turn nameof() expression to constant, which isn't any improvement btw, and only some 'string literals' related actions for the literal. The only interaction I can see is that the underline turns blue when I hover it with 'ctrl' (and then can navigate to it), so it behaves a bit like a link. I added a screenshot for clarity

Comment: Just to make sure: do these underlinings disappear when disabling R#?

Comment: @mu88 yeah. they are gone whenever I disable Resharper, together with all the lags and delays :D

Comment: So why do you use it if you don't like it 

Comment: I used it a lot some years ago, now I'm trying to figure out if it still provides enough value to justify poor performance and the annoyances, if I could turn off the options I don't like/need it would be ideal. This is one of them.